# I can't unlock my Apple ID

Tags: messages, apple-id, user-account, unlock

I want to log in to Messages on my Macbook, but it says I need to unlock my Apple ID first.

After clicking "Send to my email", I receive an unlock link, but after opening the link I can't click the "Unlock Apple ID" button.

I inspected the network and it's returning `502 Bad Gateway`:
[image]

I waited some hours but still the same. Is there any other alternative apart from answering security questions because I forgot the answers?

Comment: Did you try to clear browser caches and cookies?

Comment: @nohillside I tried to clear all cookies and cache on apple.com  but still same can't unlock. but I tried in private window I can click the button. It's strange, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I turned off the VPN, the button link is working.
Maybe Apple block Opera VPN(maybe any other VPN too).